# Better practice for huge size of table on Ruby on Rails 4 / ActiveRecord

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, sharding, rails-postgresql

fBetter practice for huge size of table on Ruby on Rails 4 / ActiveRecord

How could I partition a `big table` in the `postgreSQL` with `Active Record` on Rails 4

> I prefer PostgreSQL or other RDBMS, because I tried it in MongoDB. It is really slow on it.

Is `Rails 4` supporting good solution for a one whole big table ?

> (my case: more than `50 billions` of records, size  is about `20TB`)

## Data description

There are a `User` table containing `name, personal_data, year` fields.

The data can be divided by `year` and the data will be divided evenly.

## Ideas

I think it is `not practical` to create multiple model like `User_1950, User_2001,..., User_2015`

I want to `partition` whole  data by `year`

There are two approached I can think of

- split into different `physical table` in the same database. (sharding ?)
- split into different `physical database` on the different databases. (could it works well with Rails)

I want the solution can compatible with `Active Record`

it will act like

`User.find(name: xxx, year: 1988)` 
`User.find(name: xxx, year: 2012)`

So that I don't care about how to access the partitioned multiple tables.

[image]

## As far as I know

I found a gem `partitioned` but which is not supporting `Rails 4`

Comment: Use [inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-inheritance.html) to partition the tables: http://www.depesz.com/2015/06/07/partitioning-what-why-how/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Hi but could it also support active record on rails 4. it seems no luck on it ?

Comment: It looks like that `partitioned` gem you were looking into may support Rails 4 now https://github.com/fiksu/partitioned/issues/44

Answer (score 2):

Since you are storing the data by years, maybe you can use sharded data based on years. I would suggest [`octopus`](https://github.com/tchandy/octopus) for use with activerecord.

Your queries will become something like:

```
User.using(:year_2012).find(name: xxx)
```

Comment: will this gem put the data by year in different physical table on postgreSQL ?

Comment: You ll have to create shards yourself. But yes it shall act like a separate database instance

Comment: Thank you I will consider of it.